# couchdb emfile error

Tags: couchdb

I am testing couchdb with a pool of three workers trying to insert 200,000 records into couchdb.
After a couple of thousand records I get 500 {"error":"error","reason":"emfile"}.
Does anybody know what is the problem ?

Comment: Are you using the `_bulk_docs` API?

Comment: I am using linux, and no, I am just posting through HTTP with 5 concurrent threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might have run into this issue: [Too many view files may be held open, rendering CouchDB unusable](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-180).

Using the [_bulk_docs API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API) might be the way forward.